# Why does std::enable_shared_from_this allow multiple std::shared_ptr instances?

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr, weak-ptr, enable-shared-from-this

There are several questions that cover the behavior of `std::enable_shared_from_this`, but I don't think that this is a duplicate.

Classes that inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this` carry a `std::weak_ptr` member. When the application creates a `std::shared_ptr` pointing to a subclass of `std::enable_shared_from_this`, the `std::shared_ptr` constructor checks the `std::weak_ptr`, and if it is not initialized, initializes it and uses the `std::weak_ptr` control block for the `std::shared_ptr`. However, if the `std::weak_ptr` is already initialized, the constructor just creates a new `std::shared_ptr` with a new control block. This sets the application up to crash when the reference count of one of the two `std::shared_ptr` instances goes to zero and deletes the underlying object.

```
struct C : std::enable_shared_from_this<C> {};

C *p = new C();
std::shared_ptr<C> p1(p);

// Okay, p1 and p2 both have ref count = 2
std::shared_ptr<C> p2 = p->shared_from_this();

// Bad: p3 has ref count 1, and C will be deleted twice
std::shared_ptr<C> p3(p);
```

My question is: why does the library behave this way? If the `std::shared_ptr` constructor knows that the object is a `std::enable_shared_from_this` subclass and bothers to check the `std::weak_ptr` field, why doesn't it always use same control block for the new `std::shared_ptr`, thus avoiding a potential crash?

And for that matter, why does the method `shared_from_this` fail when the `std::weak_ptr` member is not initialized, instead of just initializing it and returning a `std::shared_ptr`?

It seems strange that the library works the way that it does, since it fails in situations when it could easily succeed. I'm wondering if there were design considerations/limitations that I don't understand.

I am using Clang 8.0.0 in C++17 mode.

Comment: For the second question, initializing a new `std::shared_ptr` instead of failing on `shared_from_this`, you can't assume how the object's lifetime is currently being managed. Unless it's owned by a raw pointer that the user won't `delete`, there really isn't a scenario where this will lead to anything good. For example, what happens if I tried `shared_from_this` with automatic storage duration?

Comment: `the std::shared_ptr constructor checks the std::weak_ptr, and if it is not initialized, initializes it and uses the std::weak_ptr control block for the std::shared_ptr` I don't think this is accurate. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/enable_shared_from_this) states that the `weak_ptr` is value initialized. I would assume that means no check is made. So adding the check would add cost to every construction that does not require it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux fair enough on the point about the object not assuming that `this` is a pointer from which a shared pointer could/should be created.

Comment: Having multiple smart pointers to the "same object" (whatever that means) isn't inherently a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you would assume that calling the constructor `shared_ptr` a second time would logically reuse the control block stored in shared_from_this.

From your point of view, this looks logical. Let's assume for a moment that `C` is part of a library your are maintaining and the usage of `C` is part of a user of your library.

```
struct C : std::enable_shared_from_this<C> {};

C *p = new C();
std::shared_ptr<C> p1(p);
std::shared_ptr<C> p3(p); // Valid given your assumption
```

Now, you found a way to no longer need the `enable_shared_from_this` and in the next version of your library, this gets updated to:

```
struct C {};

C *p = new C();
std::shared_ptr<C> p1(p);
std::shared_ptr<C> p3(p); // Now a bug
```

Suddenly, perfectly valid code becomes invalid without any compiler error/warning, because of upgrading your library. Where possible this should be prevented.

At the same time, it will cause a lot of confusion. Cause depending on the implementation of the class you put in shared_ptr, it's either defined or undefined behavior. It's less confusing to make it undefined every single time.

`enable_shared_from_this` is a standard workaround for getting a hold of a `shared_ptr` if you don't have a `shared_ptr`. A classic example:

```
 struct C : std::enable_shared_from_this<C>
 {
     auto func()
     {
         return std::thread{[c = this->shared_from_this()]{ /*Do something*/ }};
     }

     NonCopyable nc;
 };
```

Adding your mentioned extra functionality does add extra code whenever you don't need it, just for the check. Not that it would matter that much, though, zero overhead abstractions ain't nearly zero overhead abstractions.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty clear. You're saying that creating two `std::shared_ptr` instances from the same raw pointer is normally bad/undefined behavior, so it shouldn't suddenly start working just because the underlying object happens to be of some magic class. Makes sense.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Which on it's own isn't a big issue, though, it becomes a headache if you need to maintain a big code base where one of the base classes changes semantics.

Comment: Many small changes can silently break that uses `enable_shared_from_this` notably changing to private inheritance (for what many ppl believe is an implementation detail), change in stdlib impl if you made a stdlib function friend to fix the previous issue, turning an object (created with `make_shared`) into a member subobject...

Comment: @curiousguy Exactly my point. Making the standard library friend ain't a good idea, so that's one of the cases I'm least afraid of

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question but more of a reply to user [jvapen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2466431/jvapen) based on his answer to this question.

You had stated this in your answer:

> ```
> struct C {};
>
> C *p = new C();
> std::shared_ptr<C> p1(p);
> std::shared_ptr<C> p3(p); // Now a bug
> ```

What I'm not seeing here is how line 5 `std::shared_ptr<C> p3(p);` is now a bug. According to [cppreference:shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) they specifically state this:

> `std::shared_ptr` is a smart pointer that retains shared ownership of an object through a pointer. Several `shared_ptr` objects may own the same object.

Comment: If you keep reading you'll also see this: "The ownership of an object can only be shared with another shared_ptr by copy constructing or copy assigning its value to another shared_ptr. Constructing a new shared_ptr using the raw underlying pointer owned by another shared_ptr leads to undefined behavior."

Comment: @WillisBlackburn Thank you needed some clarification on that!

Comment: To weight in: you can only transfer ownership once. This would be more obvious when using `unique_ptr` for ownership, as you have to move it. That's why the general consensus is to replace new/delete with `make_unique` whenever possible.

Answer (score -1):

Creating two `shared_ptr`s to the same pointer is undefined behaviour and is nothing to do with `std::enable_shared_from_this`. Your code should be:

```
struct C : std::enable_shared_from_this<C> {};

C *p = new C();
std::shared_ptr<C> p1(p);

std::shared_ptr<C> p2 = p->shared_from_this();

std::shared_ptr<C> p3(p1);
```

Comment: The question is why the language doesn't have a feature where OP's code would work, based on `C` knowing it already has an owning `std::shared_ptr`. OP clearly communicated that they know their code is problematic.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: "*OP clearly communicated that they know their code is problematic.*" I disagree. You don't generally ask why your problematic code isn't made unproblematic. The existence of the question suggests, at least, that the OP doesn't think their code *should be* particularly problematic.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: But... the code *is bad*. That is the answer: it's not allowed because a user doing this is doing the wrong thing, so we don't let users do the wrong thing. Even though it *could* be "fixed", to "fix" it would be to say that the incoherent code is not incoherent.

Comment: @NicolBolas The question is *why* does `enable_shared_from_this` behave this way. The fact that the code is bad, and why, is explained in the question. Re-stating that is hardly an answer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux "*An analogue would be answering the question "I dropped my phone and it broke, so why don't companies make tougher phones?"*" I would say that a better analog is "I put my phone in front of my car tires and accelerated over it, and it broke. Why don't companies make phones that you can drive over?" The point of the answer here is that you're not *supposed* to be able to do these things. They're not allowed because they're not *supposed* to be allowed.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: "*Maybe nobody though of it, maybe the solution doesn't account for a technical limitation, maybe it's a trade off with something else that's more important.*" Or maybe it has nothing to do with technical limitations and has more to do with "we don't want to facilitate misuse of the API". Which is the point being made here: you aren't supposed to be able to do it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Okay, I see what you mean and it makes sense. That might be a good answer, but it isn't what this answer provides. Edit : If that *is* what the answer is trying to communicate, even rereading it with this interpretation in mind, I don't see it.

Comment: @NicolBolas you're explaining how to write code that will work given the way the standard library works today. I understand that already. I'm asking why the library works that way, instead of an arguably better way, which I describe in the question.

Comment: "_Creating two shared_ptrs to the same pointer is undefined behaviour_" Since when?

Answer (score -1):

Creating a secondary smart pointer that is either actually non owning (it does nothing when the last copy is reset/destroyed), or carries a copy of the original smart pointer in the control block (in the deleter object) such that when the secondary reference count goes to zero the primary refcount is decremented, is a very rare occurrence and would probably be confusing for most programmers, but it isn't inherently illegal. (And I think one can make a strong case for that pattern in special cases.)

On the other hand, the existence `shared_from_this` strongly suggests that there is only one owning `shared_ptr`, and so having `shared_from_this` should probably be avoided when multiple sets of `std::shared_ptr` are expected. Explicit management of self referential non owning pointers is safer as it makes such issues evident in user code, unlike the implicit behavior of `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: "And I think one can make a strong case for that pattern in special cases." Could you give some examples?

Comment: A simple example is when an object is never destroyed (or not before program termination) and you want to create non owning smart pointers to it; creating multiple independent `shared_ptr` obviously is not worse than creating just one.

Comment: The 1st para of the answer contains some actually: "_smart pointer that is either actually non owning (it does nothing when the last copy is reset/destroyed), or carries a copy of the original smart pointer in the control block (in the deleter object) such that when the secondary reference count goes to zero the primary refcount is decremented_" (Now you can find these ideas downright *bizarre* and even believe they are anti-patterns. It's subjective.)

Comment: I was looking for examples of code that uses shared-pointers-to-shared-pointers or "non-owning" shared pointers and some explanation of why such uses are necessary. You suggested that such uses could be confusing and/or bizarre but that a strong case could me made for using them. I'm wondering what that strong case would be.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn Non owning shared owning pointer is needed when you use a library component that takes a `const shared_ptr<T>&` (or `shared_ptr<T>`) and copies it in order **to extend the lifetime of the managed object**. A non owning object of course cannot extend the lifetime of anything but for a global object that is never destroyed (or only at program termination) that will be OK. You tell the library that it can extend the lifetime of an object when it really can't, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn If you have many threads using a common shared object (mostly read only) you might want to avoid the RMW atomic operation on a common shared object; you could use secondary `shared_ptr` that hold a primary `shared_ptr` so that instead of one refcount object you have many different objects and less ping pong occur between cores. Of course at the end of the day more RMW have to be performed as there are more atomic objects but with less sharing, more locality. I have no tested and I don't know any real world use and practical test of that idea.